# What is the use of .che folder in SAP UI5 projects?

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide, eclipse-che

I created a project in my SAP Web IDE. There I saw a folder named as *.che*. Can someone please explain why do we need to use that folder? What happens if we don't use it?

Comment: It contains configuration stuff for the IDE

Comment: `.che` is a hidden system folder which contains project relevant settings. App developers shouldn't care about it. Or what exactly is the reason for this question? What is the issue?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann there is no issue, i just wanted to know the purpose of its use.

Comment: This is a valid question. It's there but SAP offers little in terms of its importance. There is value on having an answer to this on SO. Please keep it open (or, provide an answer)

Answer (score 5):

SAP Web IDE is based on an open source project called [Eclipse Che](https://www.eclipse.org/che/). The IDE uses the folder.che to store some configuration information for the workspace.